# What is the goal of a time-series model?

Tags: time-series

I recently started reading online about time series and I came up with the following definition (based on a few sources). I am trying to explain it in the simplest language possible. Can anyone suggest improvements?

A time-series model attempts to explain away relationships in the data by accounting for sources of serial correlation. A good time-series model is shown by a correlogram with no bars that are above the blue line (when using the `acf()` function in R).

Comment: Something to consider: how does a time series differ from a 1D spatial series? Perhaps the notion of asymmetry/"causality" is relevant? (Many of the current answers seem like they could apply equally well to 1D spatial series)

Comment: Models (whether for time series or not) can have a variety of purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It is very restrictive. Are you mainly concerned with univariate time series? with multivariate time series you can also look at cross correlations. You can also look at the variables distribution.
If you consider time series which are random walks, then there is no serial correlation...

A model aims at simplifying something so that it can be useful / understandable / remove noise. At the end, if you gain a real understanding of the 'something' with your model, then can you explain some of its features away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a true time series, specifying it as such gives you access to a litany of mathematical analyses not (generally) otherwise possible. Seasonal decomposition. FFT. Spectral analyses. Marking modeling. Etc etc etc. If modeling is an attempt to explain variability, having knowledge of the time component takes care of a large  chunk of it.

Comment: Is "Marking modeling" intended to be "Markov modeling"?